# How to create parts inventory for Rebrickable?

Tags: part-database, inventory

I have literally thousands of pieces of LEGO from our childhood. I have sorted them and now want to scan the pieces using an app like Brickit and then import them into Rebrickable.

Is this possible? How do you save the pieces in Brickit? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have reduced your pieces to some known sets, then I'm afraid, you  have a lot of manual labour to do in order to create your initial list of elements you own. One tool that could somewhat help with that is [BrickStock](https://brickstock.patrickbrans.com).

[This guide](https://rebrickable.com/help/lists-parts/) on Rebrickable explains how you can import your elements into inventory. If the app you use could create TXT/CSV file of all scanned elements (it would be best if identify and store part ID, rather than names), the following option available on Rebrickable could be used:

> Choose a file or external site to import from. You can manually create
> your own parts file if you like, the easiest is probably a CSV
> formatted file with appropriate headings. Rebrickable will
> automatically detect the columns as long as you use the correct
> headings (in any order): Part, Color, Quantity. For example:
>
> Part,Color,Quantity
>
> 3001,15,100
>
> 92947,0,100

Color IDs can be found on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/colors/) as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex!!! That’s probably a lifetimes work